# Show that EFGH is a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram and $O$ is any point. The parallelogram $OAEB,OBFC,OCGD,ODHA$ are completed. show that $EFGH$ is a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

If you say $O$ is the origin of position vectors, then you have $$E = A+B\;\;\;{\rm and} \;\;\;F = B+C\;\;\;{\rm and} \;\;\;G = C+D\;\;\;{\rm and} \;\;\; H=A+D $$
Now $$EF = F-E = C-A = G-H = HG$$
so $EFGH$ is a parallelogram and you don't need that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.